# Which is the better way to send a broadcast signal to a great number of smarthphones in the same place?

Tags: communication, signal, bluetooth, wifi, cellphone

I wonder which could be the better way to send a broadcast signal to a great number of smartphones in the same place at the same time?

I'm thinking about 10.000 to 50.000 smartphones in an area of about 100x100 meters, and I would like to know if actual 3G cells, bluetooth, wifi or a signal to a particular frequency for the mic of each could be catched at the same time from all the phones.

My goal is to send a command to an App, and for at the same time I mean a delay < 100 milliseconds. The App once installed will ask for the permission needed, for example access to Mic, or other input devices that a common smartphone should have.

Comment: Define: "At the same time". Within seconds, minutes? If you have only one sender, 3G would probably be too slow. Bluetooth would be impractical because of distance, pairing and speed. Wifi would probably work performance wise and you could probably send ONE broadcast to all devices. I like the sound on particular frequency idea, but I don't think it would work properly with any kind of background noise.

Comment: You may want to explain your ultimate goal / what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't think a simple sound will work.  What stands a much better chance would be sending a sound modulated with a pseudo-random sequence.  Think PSK, and modulate some long sequence of bits (say, 30 or more.) Error correction is a must.

Comment: What bad thing happens if the phones don't react in time?

Comment: @JRE nothing so bad, but the signal sent should include the timestamp so in my app i could test if it is in time or not.

Comment: For sound, placing your speaker centrally gets you a delay of 20 milliSeconds for people at the far corners, leaving only 30 milliSeconds for the signal detection and reaction.

Comment: Then a PR-Sequence of maybe 15 bits and then a timestamp with checksum.

Comment: @JRE I've changed the maximum delay to 100ms, I think it should be enough for my purposes.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Start a countdown on every screen of the audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a lot of phones. If you're the network operator, system SMS / the emergency notification system could handle 10k phones but might not handle 50k phones.

Bluetooth range is ~10 meters. So you'd need a *lot* of base stations. I feel this is unlikely to work well.

Wifi would need a number of base stations, but 50k is roughly in line with what very large conferences can manage. You may need fancy APs. UDP broadcast delivery is unacknowledged so you might not get every message to every phone. It depends if rebroadcasting is fine and 95% delivery for any given broadcast is acceptable.

Audio is a very interesting option if you have control of the phones and a PA system, and there isn't too much ambient noise. No upper limit on the number of recievers. Works very well. Propagation limited to speed of sound.

(You should explain what the scenario is and whether you have administrative control over the phones and network)

Comment: The UDP unacknowledged signal should be fine. That's not an emergency notification, so 95% delivery it's ok.